# How do I find a value based on a text match from another sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, stig

I have two standards, ISO and STIG.
I am trying to match the ISO policy to STIG policy based on the common text. 
The text in ISO document is in its own cell. The text in STIG is buried in the paragraph.

Example ISO document:

```
|3.1.1.1  | Enforce Password History <random number of spaces> | etc...
```

Example STIG

```
|v-1234   | <random text> enforce password history <more text> | etc..
```

Desired outcome

```
|3.1.1.1  | v-1234  | Enforce Password History | etc...
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If ISO details are in A&B, STIG in C&D please try:

in E1:  `=INDEX($C:$D,MATCH("*"&TRIM($B1)&"*",$D:$D,0),1)` and
in F1: `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(E1)),TRIM(B1))`

Comment: thank you. I tried it (back when you posted), and found that data was far too inconsistent to use this approach.